# Block an exe from opening and open only if

Tags: windows, exe, createprocess

I wana block an exe from opening if user double clicks on it or right click and open it.
I wana make the exe open only through code like Fplatformprocess:createproc() or something similiar.

Is this possible??

Comment: What are you trying to protect against? Accidental execution can be guarded against in simple ways but if you're trying to stop the owner of the machine from deliberately running the program, no.

Comment: I wana make sure only ppl who subscibed to me can open my program. I dont wana do this in main program itself but in external program.

Comment: So you're going to solve a piracy problem that the entire games industry couldn't?

Comment: I am not making a million dollar game thats millions will play. I just want to make it not easy for ppl to use it by sharing. No1 is going to bother to crack it.

Comment: @sandy And no one will be annoyed more than 10 seconds with anything like this: "simple" solutions are to change executable's extension, or to modify ACL. Both needs _seconds_ to be modified, since you're not here and user is a local administrator. Best you can do is to use a "licence" file tested at program's startup, licence that you will extract on-the-fly before executing the program, and/or hidden command line switches... This may resist few minutes, maybe...

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible??

No.

Irrespective of the application used to launch a program (such as explorer.exe), the code will ultimately have to call into the system (usually through the Win32 `CreateProcess` API). Incidentally, that's what the `FPlatformProcess:CreateProc()` implementation uses on Windows as well.

You cannot have a system API call that both succeeds and fails at the same time, in the same environment, given the same input.